# access to the coupon information in the webbook in stripe

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I am using coupon in stripe checkout session. it works fine but I need to store the information once checkout successfully completed in my server. I am thinking of either of the following potential solutions:

1- pass the info to webhook:

```
@csrf_exempt
def stripe_webhook(request, **myextrainfo**):
```

2- somehow find the used coupon info in the webhook

```
event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
            payload, sig_header, endpoint_secret
        )
```

I don't know if the first is doable and about the second, I can almost retrieve all the information like customer, product, total, subtotal but I cannot find coupon info. here is information that I can retrieve:

```
session = event['data']['object']
line_items = stripe.checkout.Session.list_line_items(session['id'], limit=1)
print(line_items)
print(line_items["data"][0]["price"]["id"])
print(line_items["data"][0]["price"]["product"])
print(line_items["data"][0]["price"]["recurring"]["interval"])
print(line_items["data"][0]["price"]["recurring"]["interval_count"])
```

I appreciate if someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I found the info in another event:

```
if event['type']=='invoice.payment_succeeded':
    # print(event.data)
    # print(event.data.object)
    print("customer: ",event.data.object.customer)
    print("customer_email: ",event.data.object.customer_email)
    print("coupon strip id: ",event.data.object.discount.coupon.id)
    print("url: ",event.data.object.hosted_invoice_url)
    print("invoice number",event.data.object.number)
    print("Product: ",event.data.object.lines.data[0].plan.product)
    print("priceID: ",event.data.object.lines.data[0].price.id)
    print("plan interval: ",event.data.object.lines.data[0].price.recurring.interval)
    print("plan interval count: ",event.data.object.lines.data[0].price.recurring.interval_count)

    print("start: ",event.data.object.period_start)
    print("end: ",event.data.object.period_end)
    print("subtotal: ",event.data.object.subtotal)
    print("discount: ",event.data.object.total_discount_amounts[0].amount)
    print("total: ",event.data.object.total)
```